# Cakephp 2 Paginate Order By Closest Date

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I am trying to get the list of results from the Orders table in my CakePhp 2.x application to sort themselves by the date closest to today.

In a usual mysql query I have had something similar working with say the following syntax:

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(Order.duedate, NOW()))
```

However in Cake I am not sure how to get such a custom query to work within the paginate helper. Is this something I may need to set in a finder query in the model?

Here is the controller I currently have (set to a bog standard descending sort)

```
    public function index() {
           $this->paginate = array( 
                    'conditions' => array (
                        'Order.despatched' => array('Not Despatched' , 'Split Despatched')
                    ),
                    'limit' => 25,
                    'order' => array('Order.duedate' => 'DESC')
            );

           $data = $this->paginate('Order');
           $this->set('orders', $data);
}
```

Edit: Using information from the comment below I added a virtual field into the controller which causes an sql error. At first I thought this was due to the associations within the model, to attempt to rectify this I added the virtualField into the Order Model and into the constructor of the associated Account Model. However this made no change to the part of the sql which breaks. The full sql error is:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `Order__closestdate`, `Account`.`id`, `Account`.`company`, `Account`.`contac' at line 1

SQL Query: SELECT `Order`.`id`, `Order`.`order_id`, `Order`.`orderdate`,
 `Order`.`duedate`, `Order`.`rework`, `Order`.`rework_notes`, `Order`.`comments`, 
`Order`.`status`, `Order`.`customer`, `Order`.`last_edited`, `Order`.`value`, 
`Order`.`quantity`, `Order`.`order_for`, `Order`.`warehouse`, `Order`.`haulier`, 
`Order`.`terms`, `Order`.`type`, `Order`.`despatched`, `Order`.`despatched_date`, 
`Order`.`invoiced`, `Order`.`invoice_date`, `Order`.`bookingref`, 
`Order`.`purchaseref`, `Order`.`payment_due`, `Order`.`payment_status`, 
`Order`.`payment_date`, (ABS(DATEDIFF(duedate, NOW())) AS `Order__closestdate`, 
`Account`.`id`, `Account`.`company`, `Account`.`contact`, `Account`.`phone`, 
`Account`.`email`, `Account`.`postcode`, `Account`.`created`, `Account`.`modified`, 
`Account`.`customer`, `Account`.`address1`, `Account`.`address2`, `Account`.`town`, 
`Account`.`county`, (ABS(DATEDIFF(duedate, NOW())) AS `Account__closestdate` FROM 
`hunter_om`.`orders` AS `Order` LEFT JOIN `hunter_om`.`accounts` AS `Account` ON 
(`Order`.`customer` = `Account`.`customer`) WHERE `Order`.`despatched` IN ('Not 
Despatched', 'Split Despatched') ORDER BY (ABS(DATEDIFF(duedate, NOW())) DESC LIMIT 25
```

For reference the code in the models are:

```
//Order Model
public $virtualFields = array(
   'closestdate' => 'ABS(DATEDIFF(duedate, NOW())'
);

//Account Model
  public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
   parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
   $this->virtualFields['closestdate'] = $this->Order->virtualFields['closestdate'];
   }
```

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a 'virtualField' to the Order model before paginating;

```
$this->Order->virtualFields['closestdate'] = "ABS(DATEDIFF(Order.duedate, NOW()))";
```

Then use that field as a regular field in your query/paginate

```
public function index() {

    $this->Order->virtualFields['closestdate'] = "ABS(DATEDIFF(Order.duedate, NOW()))";

    $this->paginate = array( 
        'conditions' => array (
            'Order.despatched' => array('Not Despatched' , 'Split Despatched')
        ),
        'limit' => 25,
        'order' => array('Order.closestdate' => 'DESC')
    );

    $data = $this->paginate('Order');
    $this->set('orders', $data);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, this solution gives me an sql syntax error with (ABS(DATEDIFF(duedate, NOW())) AS `Order__closestdate` being the culprit. I assumed this was something to do with the associations in the models (according to the cookbook this causes sql problems) however I tried constructing the virtualFields in the models and the error still appears. Have you any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the complete SQL of the query that generates the error? Maybe add it to your original question, because formatting in comment blocks is limited

Comment: Hi, I have added the additional information to the original question.

Comment: @DevelopingTheWeb I missed a closing ')' in my virtualField, which was causing an error. Also I spotted you're not using the 'Order.' prefix before 'duedate', although this is not strictly required, it may cause problems if multiple tables in your query have a 'duedate' field ('ambiguous column'). I fixed the code in my answer

Comment: Ah its always something simple like that when I asked question on here. Its working fine now, also I had the unambiguous method first in the code but changed it to see if it would helped me find the error. Changed back now thanks.